# Dictionary comprehension from a list of tuples with lists in them

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose I have a variable structured as so:

```
results = [([123], 456),
 ([1, 2, 3], 456),
 ([2], 456)]
```

I want to get it into a dictionary using dictionary comprehension which I achieve doing so:

```
{item[1]:set(i for item in results for i in item[0]) for item in results}

{456: {1, 2, 3, 123}}
```

However now suppose variable `results` becomes this:

```
[([123], 456),
 ([1, 2, 3], 456),
 ([2], 456),
 ([789], 'fizz')]
```

I have unsuccessfully attempted to change my comprehension to work on this case. How would I achieve this result through the use of dictionary comprehension? I know how to do it using loops but I wish to learn how this is achieved using comprehension. Thanks!

Edit:

Output would be as so:

```
{456: {1, 2, 3, 123}, 'fizz': {789}}
```

Comment: where did the `744` come from? And your code does not run for me.

Comment: What is the output format!?

Comment: sorry I ran it on different data before I properly pasted it here, its changed now

Comment: edited for output and the code works fine, I just ran it with no problems

Comment: I get an error for undefined `item` in your dict comprehension on both python 2.7 and 3.5. What version are you using?

Comment: @AustinHastings 2.7

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy `item[1]` that you are using as a key cannot be defined; it is outside the comprehension

Comment: @AustinHastings Use `{item[1]:set(i for item in results for i in item[0]) for item in results}` instead of `{item[1]:set(i for item in results for i in item[0])}`. That way, item is defined for use in the dict comprehension.

Comment: Just do it with `defaultdict(set)` and a loop, a comprehension is likely just going to end up being unreadable.

Comment: Its not about being readable, its about me trying to learn something which is why I mentioned that I know how to do it with loops in my post.

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy Fair enough but some things are not supposed to be done in comprehensions. There are good and bad applications for them. This is a bad one imho

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy why are you trying to learn the *wrong way* to use a comprehension? Just use a loop. This is not a use-case for a comprehension, and would require some hacky mix of state-change (which you shouldn't mix with comprehension constructs) to achieve

Comment: Thanks anyways guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily do this without a comprehension, but if you insist on a comprehension, here's a solution that uses `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
import operator

f = operator.itemgetter(1)
r = {k: set(i for x in g for i in x[0]) for k, g in groupby(results, f)}
print(r)
# {456: set([3, 1, 2, 123]), 'fizz': set([789])}
```

**Caveat:** Note that **no presorting** is done, since the items are already arranged according to the group key.

The solution is more readable (say more Pythonic) with a simple for loop that uses `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

r = defaultdict(set)
for v, k in results:
   r[k].update(v)
print(r)
# defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {456: set([3, 1, 2, 123]), 'fizz': set([789])})
```

Comment: Thank you! Regardless of whether or not this was the right way to do it I wanted to see how it was done using comprehension so I can learn more about comprehensions. Thank you for simply answering the question.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Items are fortunately presorted

Comment: Yeah, but that wasn't explicitly stated as a given, so perhaps it is a good caveat to note in the answer.

Comment: What sorting is there to do? The result is a dict and sets, which are both unordered collections

Comment: The comprehension was exactly what I was looking for especially since I haven't used `operator` a lot and it exposed me to something new. Well done, thanks!

Comment: @FélixCaron `groupby` *conventionally* requires that the items in an iterable be sorted on the group key.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using only dictionary and set comprehension:

```
{b: {k for x, y in results for k in x if y == b} for a, b in results}
```